# Can I change the Type discriminator property in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, polymorphism

I am having trouble moving between mongodb and json.net due to polymorphic types.  the c# mongodb driver users _t as the discriminator property name and json.net uses $type.  I know json.net has this value hardcoded from other research.  My question is if anyone knows of a way to rename "_t" to "$type" using the c# mongodb driver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can can create a custom discriminator convention and you can add it to each type you wish to modify;

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/

Here's an example of a custom discriminator convention which might help you;

http://pastebin.com/9UweEKBe